# Prevent User from changing html in CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I wonder, if there is a way to prevent users from harming any html within my default html in a CKeditor textfield.

Yes I know this is not the Drupal way. Normally I would create a paragraph with its own fields. This is also not really a Drupal specific question as CKeditor is an independent project.

It's a totally different approach to allow users to just change text within predefined areas (tags) without giving them a way to remove or change any html as it just acts as some kind of frame.

I have not find this feature on the CKeditor site. I wonder if anybody thought about this away of content editoring.

Comment: I disagree with this closing. CKEditor is part of Drupal core and it's a custom version of CKEditor. Answers for regular CKEditor usually do not transfer directly D8's version.

Comment: You could make use of [CKEditor Templates](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_templates) and don't give the user access to the source code button.

Comment: Give the last two sentences, it doesn't seem a Drupal question, but a question about creating a rather complex CKEditor plugin.

Comment: I found a very very simple solution.

Comment: Solution: adding the attribute contenteditable="false" to the wrapping html tag prevents users from harming any html as the html is not changeable any longer via editor. Nice is also that you can add it on the top level wrapping element and then add the "true" attribute on every text or image tag. Now I can use ckeditor templates which act more like a form mask for values... just like the a paragraph for example. I will stick to paragraphs. But this feature does work perfect when you just don't have the time to create entities. Ps. Don't forget to remove the attribute from the frontend.